# Does "is_linux" variable have special meaning?

Tags: c, variables

I don't understand why the result of the `if` statement below is always incorrect:

```
unsigned long is_linux;
printf("plz. enter a digit : ");

gets(str);
sscanf(str,"%d",&is_linux);

printf("the value of is_linux = %d \n",is_linux);
if(is_linux==1)
    printf("Here is 1 ! \n");
else
    printf("There is 0 ! \n");
```

I can only get "There is 0 !" statement, even if I entered "1". Furthermore, `printf()` statement displays the value of `is_linux` (1) correctly:

> ```
> plz. enter a digit : 1
> the value of is_linux = 1 
> There is 0 !
> ```

It works well if I change the variable to another name, for instance,`test`. Is there any reason for not using `is_linux` variable ? I've compiled above source code using `gcc` at `x86_64-redhat-linux`.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: gets() is non-standard, use `fgets()`.

Comment: Is `is_linux` global / static variable or automatic? For test add `static` in the definition.

Comment: Note that `sscanf("str, "%d", &is_linux)` is incorrect.  An `unsigned long` should be read using `%lu` or a related conversion specification with the `l` length modifier specified.  On a 64-bit (non-Windows) machine, the chances are that your scan sets only 4 bytes of an 8-byte integer; the other 4 bytes are probably not zero, so your tests fail.  Why don't you print `is_linux` — carefully: `printf("is_linux = %lu\n", is_linux);`?

Comment: It is better to use `strtol` instead of `sscanf`.

Comment: Are you working on a Windows machine, or a 64-bit Unix-like machine, or a 32-bit Unix-like machine?  It matters.  Your code is dubious because it is using the wrong conversion specification, but if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)` — as it does on most 32-bit systems and Windows 64, but not on 64-bit Unix-like systems — then you might get away with it.  From the results you're seeing, you're probably working on a 64-bit Unix-like machine with a 64-bit compilation mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code

```
  sscanf(str,"%d",&is_linux);
```

causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

`is_linux` is of type `unsigned long`, it demands the conversion specifier to be `lu`.

Passing wrong (mismatched) type of argument to any conversion specifier  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: In many cases `unsigned long` has the same size like `unsigned int`. Maybe the reason is different.

Comment: @i486 It's also a signedness problem, despite having same size.

Comment: In the question the value is `1` and sign does not affect.

Comment: @i486 does the problem go away if you use `%lu`?

Comment: I find it way too amusing that someone called i486 would say that `unsigned long` has the same size as `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should be able to use the variable name.  `is_linux` is not reserved and it's not a keyword. Worst-case scenario, it could (but shouldn't) be a macro (`linux` commonly is, unfortunately). Preemptively, or if you get compilation errors because it is a macro on your platform, you could `#undef` it first. 
(Make sure the rest of your code is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

The datatype you are assigning to is_linux is not compatible. You set it as a long, but giving it an int so when you check with your if statement you are checking for a long value, not int.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, there.
All comments were very helpful to me for finding root cause.
Actually, it was very simple reason, data type.
Simply, I changed %d to %lu in both of sscanf and printf and got correct answer.

My machine was 64bit lunux system and it treated unsigned long as 8-byte unit.
And also, I misunderstood %d could cover all the integer data types.
Anyway, I'm very appreciate all you guy's comments. Thank you :)